# Eclipse maven EAR project not working after git share

Tags: java, git, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a working maven project on eclipse which I made using the archetype for Jakarta EE with an ear packaging using windfly 21. (org.windfly.archetype - wildfly-jakartaee-ear-archetype).

After i got a working webpage, i decided to share it on git, using the eclipse GUI. (Right click on project -> Team -> Share).

This moves the project onto another folder, as it says that having git repositories inside eclipse default workspace folder is not recommended.

**The problem** is that after sharing it, even before I commit or push, it stops working. It stops recognizing packages and I'm unable to make it "run on server".

This is an image of how it looks after I share it on git. I cannot execute "p1parte1" or "p1parte1-ear" anymore (neither any of the other projects/modules), and the other projects below dont have the java classes inside.

[image: Image of problem]

I literally have no idea how to fix this, i've spent like 3 hours searching online and trying things.

Comment: Could you please give us the output of `git status` executed on your project root directory? If it is the first time you use git, I really recommend that you use your terminal to work with git. Really it's so easy and you will find enough resources on the internet when you encounter a problem...

Comment: Did you check whether your java files are still there somewhere?  Are the original projects within the Eclipse workspace folder still there, and still complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by manually fully copying the project that was not shared in the eclipse workspace folder to the git folder.